# Add Button in Leaflet PopUp

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, popup

i have installed a leaflet map and have tried several times to add a popup to the map that supports HTML text and contains a button.
The problem with the below version is that the button appears but when you try to add a function when the button is pressed it doesn't work.

```
var popup = L.popup({
        offset: [0, -30]
    })

map.on('click', (e) => {
    const lng = e.latlng.lng,
        lat = e.latlng.lat
    $('#lng').val(lng)
    $('#lat').val(lat)
    $('#phi').val(CalcBeta(lat))
    AddMarker(lat, lng)
    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent('<b>Your selected Location</b><br>Longitude: '+e.latlng.lng.toString()+'<br>Latitude: '+e.latlng.lat.toString()+'<br>Power supply: test<br>Water supply: test<br>Panel tilt angle: '+CalcBeta(lat)+'<br><br><center><button id="getres">More details</button>')
        .openOn(map);
    
    
})
```

The other version I found in a forum is the one below where the button works but you can't use HTML text inside the popup.

```
//var choicePopUp = L.popup();
//var container = L.DomUtil.create('div');
//var txtcontent = document.createTextNode('');
//container.append(txtcontent);

//Btn = this.createButton('Go to this location', container);


//choicePopUp
//  .setLatLng(e.latlng)
//  .setContent(container)
//  .openOn(this.map);

//L.DomEvent.on(Btn, 'click', () => {
//  alert("tata");
//});
```

Do you have an idea how to get the 1st or the 2nd version or maybe a completely different approach?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind a click to your button, you need to bind the click event in the same scope as you create the `Popup`.

You can do this in this way :

```js
map.on('click', (e) => {
    const lng = e.latlng.lng;
    const lat = e.latlng.lat;

    $('#lng').val(lng);
    $('#lat').val(lat);
    $('#phi').val(CalcBeta(lat));

    AddMarker(lat, lng);

    popup.setLatLng(e.latlng)
         .setContent('<b>Your selected Location</b><br>Longitude: '
             + e.latlng.lng.toString()
             + '<br>Latitude: '
             + e.latlng.lat.toString()
             + '<br>Power supply: test<br>Water supply: test<br>Panel tilt angle: '
             + CalcBeta(lat)
             + '<br><br><center><button id="getres">More details</button>')
        .openOn(map);

    // We bind the click event here in the same scope as we add the Popup
    document.getElementById('getres').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log('click !');
        // Here you can do your stuff
    });
})
```